# VBA Select Multiple Worksheets Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I spent some time searching for an answer but had no luck.

I'm trying to create a macro that will select multiple worksheets based on user input from an input box and combine it with a LIKE operator to select all the worksheets at once. Each of these sheets has a different name but all begin with a 5 digit number, 20001 for example, that I can use as a criteria for selection.

I can get this to work if I hard code the 5 digit value and select multiple sheets at once but can't get it to work with the input box value. I've tried different iterations of entering the input box value/variable but haven't had any luck.

Example Below with input box:

```vba
Public Sub SixPayTest()
    Dim Bunumber As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Bunumber = Application.InputBox("Enter BU #")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       If ws.Name Like bunumber Then ws.Select (False)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

This Working example below will select all the worksheet I need it to but without the input box:

```vba
Public Sub SixPayTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       If ws.Name Like "*20001*" Then ws.Select (False)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Most of the time there is no need to select anything. Could you share your end goal i.e. what are you planning to do with this selection? I'm asking so you could receive a more useful code. Here's a tip: if this code is in the active workbook, you should replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` to ensure it doesn't run on the wrong workbook. Also, *False* should be without parentheses i.e. `ws.Select False` or `ws.Select Replace:=False`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add wildcards for like value. For example:

```
If ws.Name Like "*" & bunumber & "*" Then
    ....
```

Even clearer would be to update value before like conditon.

```
bunumber="*" & bunumber & "*"
```

Also, if you want to find sheet with name starting with bnumber, do not add first star "*" to the string.

Comment: Thank you that placement of the "*" solved my issue I didn't think about that.